# python loop not looping how I expect

Tags: python

I've spent the last two hours trying to figure this out. Please help I've tried Google for the past two hours. No luck. What am I doing wrong?

The contents of codes.txt:

```
TKF6J-KXP6V-F499V-Q9XPC-7J6TZ;J9YCV-D4TH6-WWWWV-F2RM7-F63XZ;GXKCC-QDT34-3JRY4-TWKHX-R763Z;
```

myscript.py

```
import re
from sqlalchemy import *

string = open("codes.txt").readlines()

for item in string:
    set = [item.split(";")]
    print "success"
```

Why does it print "success" only once? I expect it to print success for the number of items in codes.txt.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readlines()` is actually looking for newline characters, and since it doesn't appear that your string has any, it is only reading one line, and therefore only returning one element (this is what @kayZhu just said, apologies :) ). I think you are looking to split on the semicolon, so you could try this:

```
In [19]: with open('codes.txt', 'r') as f:
   ....:     contents = f.read().split(';')
   ....:
   ....:

In [20]: contents
Out[20]:
['TKF6J-KXP6V-F499V-Q9XPC-7J6TZ',
 'J9YCV-D4TH6-WWWWV-F2RM7-F63XZ',
 'GXKCC-QDT34-3JRY4-TWKHX-R763Z',
 '']
```

And then your iteration should work as expected. Also, try to avoid using Python built-in names for your variables (e.g. `string` - it will only cause heartache down the road :) ).

Comment: @DavidNeudorfer No problem at all, happy it helped!

Answer (score 3):

`readlines` depends on the newline character `\n` to separate lines into a list. In your case, the contents of codes.txt is just one line and therefore the entire list `string` contain only one element inside.

Comment: +1 because you had the true answer ahead of me (sorry for repeating :) ).

Answer (score 1):

Ask yourself this: what do you expect `item` to be on the first iteration? The second? etc. Then do this:

```
for item in string:
    print item
```

And see how it compares to your expectations.

The result of `open("codes.txt").readlines()` will have one element for every *line* in the file (it has no idea of any deeper meaning you might associate with the name `item`). Your file currently only has one line - if you add another, so it looks like this:

```
TKF6J-KXP6V-F499V-Q9XPC-7J6TZ;J9YCV-D4TH6-WWWWV-F2RM7-F63XZ;GXKCC-QDT34-3JRY4-TWKHX-R763Z;
TKF6J-KXP6V-F499V-Q9XPC-7J6TZ;J9YCV-D4TH6-WWWWV-F2RM7-F63XZ;GXKCC-QDT34-3JRY4-TWKHX-R763Z;
```

(ie, double the line you have currently), and you will see that it prints twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
string = open("code.txt").readlines()

string= "".join(string)

for item in string.split(";"):

    if len(item)>1:

        print "success"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  with open(r'C:\Python33\1_.txt') as f:
  d =f.read().split(';')
  for a in d:
      print(a)
```

Other version of iteration